# jQuery: Audio scroll bar using jQuery UISlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, audio

So with my seekbar, image down below, users should be able to jump to a place in the song they desire by changing where the handle is on the seekbar, and the slider handle should change by what part of the song it's in right now.

[image: slider!]

What is happening right now is this.

This is my slider setup:

```
$("#progressbar1").slider({
    value  : 0,
    step   : 1,
    range  : false,
    min    : 0,
    max    : firstSongDuration,
    change  : function(){
    var value = $("#progressbar1").slider("value");
    $("#audio1")[0].currentTime = value;
}
});
```

This is my setup detecting where in the song it is at currently:

```
$("#audio1")[0].addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){
    firstSongDuration = Math.floor($("#audio1")[0].duration);
    setTime(firstSongDuration, $("#endingTime1"));
    firstSongCurrently = Math.floor($("#audio1")[0].currentTime);
    setTime(firstSongCurrently, $("#currentTime1"));
},false);
```

and what is happening right now is that when I click to a different spot on the slider, the slider and the audio just get confused and stay where it's at.

What seems to be happening is that when I move to a different part of the slider, `firstSongCurrently`(my variable for what part of the song it's at right now, integer) gets assigned the new value of the slider. But, in the same function, firstSongCurrently is also being assigned the value of what part of the song it is right now (the second code snippet).

The problem seems to maybe be at the fact that both of those things are in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

???

I am lost in figuring out how to fix this and have looked into various different posts and articles on how to go about using the slider.

It MUST be simpler than this!!!

Thank you everyone!